# UNIT Test Fails, throws COMException "There is no MTS object context"

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a unit test that contains several test cases. I set them up through the Test Project wizard. It is pretty standard procedure.

When I choose to run one of the test, I got the following error

> Test method et.Exec.ProductionBase.Test.etProcessQCItemExecTest.CreateTest threw exception:  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: There is no MTS object context (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004E004).

I couldn't figure out how to resolve this. I did a little bit of digging online, but none seems to help. All Help is greatly appreciated.

I am running VSTS 2008 Development Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be exercising production code that depends on having MTS installed. That would be called an integration test.

You need to decouple the production code *under test* from the MTS dependency and test in isolation (which would be a unit test).